# popup blocker settings direct link

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to make sure users logging into my site have popups blocked for my domain in Firefox and Chrome. Is there a direct link to the settings in each browser that a user can click on so it's not a 6 step process to get into the settings -> advanced -> privacy settings -> etc.?

Similar request to this [request post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions/1QSLcuIJe3U) (copied for posterity):

> It would be really cool if I could also have a URL to either execute a search OR link to a specific setting. Shouldn't be too hard to implement.
>
> Like: chrome://settings/advanced?#proxiesLabel to point a user to the proxy settings.
>
> The only counter argument is by allowing this you create a de facto API, so you might want to consider a way to allow for changed ids or only commit to support ids on certain settings following a specified pattern on the id like "gotoTranslationSettings".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both *Firefox* and *Chrome* use their own protocols to display the dialogs.

Here's the page that shows you several addresses in *Firefox*:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:_Firefox_Chrome_URLs

In *Chrome* it's more obvious because the links are shown in the address bar. For instance: `chrome://settings/`

Browse this page with *Chrome* for more information:
`chrome://about/`